# Safely merging multiple MySQL users to %

Tags: mysql, linux, database, config

Was recently managing my MySQL (5.5.41) on Linux machine and decided to remove/merge MySQL initially created `root` users.

Quoting [MySQL 5.5 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html) (also nice [article here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59412/multiple-root-users-in-mysql))

> On Unix, each root account permits connections from the local host. Connections can be made by specifying the host name localhost, the IP address 127.0.0.1, the IPv6 address ::1, or the actual host name or IP address.

The `user` table is as follows

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host      | User             | Password                                  |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root             | *ABC...                                   |
| lamp      | root             |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             | *ABC...                                   |
| ::1       | root             |                                           |
| localhost | john             | *EFG...                                   |
| lamp      | john             |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1 | john             | *EFG...                                   |
| ::1       | john             |                                           |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

It is also set to listen only to localhost `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`. The question is

- What could be the possible downfalls of merging multiple `root` users to a single one and using `%` wildcard as `Host` ?
- Some of the passwords are blank thus not required to login. If `%` is used and password is set some users (`lamp`, IPv6 `::1`) would not be able to login. Should this be avoided?
- What could be the best pracice - to create a new user basing on initial create (`127.0.0.1`, `::1`, `localhost`) or to stick with the `%` wildcard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, i'd suggest you avoid using `%` wildcard (if it's not strictly necessary). If your users connect to the database from the same host the mysql server is running on, my advice is to use `127.0.0.1`

All best practices point out that no-password login should be disabled.

As for IPv6, there's no point in having that user if you're not using it.

I'd suggest you read this http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips

Comment: I am not using lamp or localhost user as well - it is used by system. Could they be removed?

Comment: if you're using the default DNS settings (and localhost and lamp _are_ converted to 127.0.0.1), it's safe to remove them. They are placed there strictly for this purpose. Just for your peace of mind, before you remove them for `root`, remove them for `john` (leaving just the `john@127.0.0.1`) and see if you can connect from the terminal, mysql-workbench and the application.

Comment: IMHO, the loopback is done in /etc/hosts (my hosts file does not contain these records). I am still unsure about the no-password logins: on one hand it does look like A GIANT security hole but on the other it may be viable for system to have them...